# How to use EXACT (A1,A2) values with date in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making an excel sheet which has days and dates in the format . For example

```
A1 Day: Monday 
A2 Date: 10-Nov
```

I am changing the color of that cell with custom rule that

```
 =EXACT(A1,"Monday") , then change A4,A5,A6 cell ---> Red color
```

Till now all was good. But the problem is that now in 2016 March and November has same A1 as Monday . So I tried to do like this

```
 =EXACT(A2,"10-Nov") ---> then change A4,A5,A6 cell ---> No color
```

Its not working . It seems it not matching the value. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `10-Nov` in A2 is the *representation* of a date, not the date itself. You could try something like:

```
=EXACT(TEXT(A2, "dd-mmm"),"10-Nov")
```

In other words, compare the textual representations of the date instead of the date itself.

Alternatively, you could compare the dates directly:

```
=A2=DATE(2016,11,10)
```

Comment: Perfect ! Awesome :)